# Canvas: Animate bezier curve drawing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

im trying to make a line that crossing the canvas from left to right. im still in early stage to achieve that، to do that im using the following function to do the step by step animation

```
timer = window.setInterval(draw_line, 30);
```

my drawing function is like this

```
function draw_line()
    {
        context.fillStyle = "#000";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, canv.width, canv.height);

            context.beginPath();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = '#fff';

            //Where p1, p2, cp1, cp2 are point objects that has x & y values already defined    
        context.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
        context.bezierCurveTo(cp1.x,cp1.y,cp2.x,cp2.y,p2.x,p2.y);
        context.stroke();
        context.closePath();

            // now i have to move p1, p2 ,cp1,cp2
            // now here is my problem
    }
```

i understand that i need to move  `p1.x+= a random number;` and also the same for cp1 and cp2, but what about **p2** the End point it should follow the line same track ! how can i achieve that ?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edited answer**

With your clarification, I think I can answer this appropriately now.

In order to have the end point follow the path the start point took through the canvas, you have to store the historical values. In this example, http://jsfiddle.net/mobidevelop/bGgHQ/, I use mouse movements to fill a buffer of the last 16 positions, then use that to form a bezier curve through the points by iterating over the RingBuffer.

```
function RingBuffer(length) {
    this.length = length;
    this.pointer = 0;
    this.buffer = [];
}
RingBuffer.prototype.get = function(index) {
    if (index < 0) {
        index += this.length;        
    }
    return this.buffer[index];
}
RingBuffer.prototype.push = function(value) {
    this.buffer[this.pointer] = value;
    this.pointer = (this.length + this.pointer +1) % this.length;    
}

var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context =c.getContext("2d");

timer = window.setInterval(draw_line, 30);
function Point(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
Point.prototype.translateX = function(x) {
    return this.x += x;
};
Point.prototype.translateY = function(y) {
    return this.y += y;
};

function draw_line()
{
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    var pointer = history.pointer;
    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = '#F00';     
    for (iteration = 0, count = 15; iteration < count; iteration += 3) {
        var p1 = history.get(--pointer);
        var p2 = history.get(--pointer);
        var p3 = history.get(--pointer);
        var p4 = history.get(--pointer);        

        if (p1 && p2 && p3 && p4) {

            context.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
            context.bezierCurveTo(p2.x, p2.y, p3.x, p3.y, p4.x, p4.y);

        }
        pointer++;
    }
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();    

}

var history = new RingBuffer(16);
var lastGrab = new Date();
c.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
    now = new Date();
    if (now - lastGrab > 15) {
        history.push(new Point(event.clientX - c.offsetLeft, event.clientY - c.offsetTop)); 
        lastGrab = now;
    }    
});​
```

---

**Previous answer left below, for historical purposes.**

I am not sure I completely understand what you are trying to achieve, but I think all you need to do is translate all of your points by the same value. This will result in the line traversing the canvas keeping the same shape. something like this:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mobidevelop/7wsLW/)

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var context =c.getContext("2d");

timer = window.setInterval(draw_line, 30);
function Point(x,y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
Point.prototype.translateX = function(x) {
    return this.x += x;
};
Point.prototype.translateY = function(y) {
    return this.y += y;
};

var p1 = new Point(0,0);
var p2 = new Point(100,100);
var cp1 = new Point(15,45);
var cp2 = new Point(85,45);

function draw_line()
{
    context.fillStyle = "#000";
    context.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    context.beginPath();
    context.lineWidth = 2;
    context.strokeStyle = '#fff';

        //Where p1, p2, cp1, cp2 are point objects that has x & y values already defined    
    context.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
    context.bezierCurveTo(cp1.x,cp1.y,cp2.x,cp2.y,p2.x,p2.y);
    context.stroke();
    context.closePath();

    p1.translateX(1);
    p2.translateX(1);
    cp1.translateX(1);
    cp2.translateX(1);

    if (p1.x > 300) {
        p1.translateX(-400);
        p2.translateX(-400);
        cp1.translateX(-400);
        cp2.translateX(-400);        
    }
}
```

Unless I am misunderstanding the goal...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what im trying to achieve is a point that has a tail. the first point p1 moves in a random direction and the second point p2 follows the p1 tail

Comment: Interesting, I would never have gotten that from your description of the problem... And unfortunately, I am still confused. Do you have a visual example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: @ra_htial are you looking more for something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/mobidevelop/bGgHQ/ (Move your mouse around the canvas)